How to process notification sequentially from salesforce to external systems?
How to process notification sequentially from salesforce to external systems ?
We are seeing sometime the execution order is not properly handled within salesforce using Queueable.
For Example:
External System is Sending Notification to Salesforce.
To Process the Notification in Salesforce, We are using platform Event with After Insert Trigger.
In the After Insert Trigger, we are calling the Queable to process the business Logic(callout,Other tasks etc).
Now when the First Notification comes to SF,PE will process it using queable(for Example it might take 5s) and will update the status to 'Activated'.
For Second Notification,PE will process it using same logic but for this Nofication(we have less business logic),its taking less time and Status is being updated to 'Completed'.
Due to Async nature of Queable ,Second notification is being processed First and Then First Notification which is causing the Issue.
If we can somehow make it in One after another,that will solve the issue.
I am considering to Use delay in Queable jobs while enquing it.Any other solution will be appreciated.

More details would be helpful.

I think the only solution that guarantees a sequence is Platform Events, but as Derek says, hard to know without more information

Getting two separate platform events, with an unknown interval between them and no way to coordinate with the system that's publishing the events, makes things a bit tricky.
I'm not entirely sure why you're going async in the platform event (PE) trigger (the PE trigger itself is capable of performing DML).
While setting a delay on the queueable that changes your record status to "Completed" is one option, I'd probably look at (in no particular order):

checking to see if your target record's status is already past the "Activated" stage (and only doing the update in the PE 1's logic if the record status is not "Completed"). The simple solution if you don't need to care about the precise order in which things are done (as long as you end up in the right end state)
record locking using FOR UPDATE in a query for the record(s) that you're trying to update

The FOR UPDATE solution would work, assuming that PE 1 starts being processed before PE 2 does. The logic for PE 2 would be forced to wait until PE 1 completes (thus releasing the lock(s) that PE 1 has on the record(s)). You'd want to catch the UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW exception (System.QueryException, I think?) in case you can't obtain the lock so you can retry the PE trigger
Beyond that, I think that things start to get more convoluted/complex. Something like:

Make a separate SObject to act as an "intent log", your PE trigger would only insert records to that other SObject (probably also a good idea to have an "operation number" field so you can later sort by it and tolerate PE 2 arriving before PE 1). You'd probably want a "ParentId" field (master-detail or lookup if you're only working with a single SObject, a plain text field marked as an external id if you're working with multiple SObjects)
Have a scheduled batch class (queueable could possibly work, but batch is probably better suited here) that is run every, say, 15 minutes to pick up the "intent" records and actually process them (in order).
You'd want to have a time cutoff for the query in the start() method (e.g. WHERE CreatedDate <= :Datetime.now().addMinutes(-5), with the exact cutoff being something like 3+ standard deviations between the arrival of PE 1 and PE 2) and then gather the parent Ids and re-query the intent records for those parent ids in the execute() method so you (mostly) avoid a race condition (when, say, PE 2 gets inserted really close to that 15 minute time boundary)

In the end, this is going to be a trade-off. Simplicity, guarantee of processing order, and prompt updating of data in Salesforce; you'll only be able to choose 2.
